# Opening GeoServer Admin returns HTTP ERROR: 503?

Tags: geoserver

I try to open Geoserver Admin and returns the following error.

> HTTP ERROR: 503
>
> Problem accessing /geoserver/web/. Reason:
>
> Service Unavailable

What is causing this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As it stands I think your question is too broad because, although you have provided an error message, you have not provided any additional information like the versions of GeoServer, Operating System, and other software you are using, nor have you told us whether this has just been installed, or was working previously, etc, etc.  There is an edit button beneath your question that you can use to revise it.

Answer (score 1):

Something went wrong during deploy.

More information is needed to help out:

- which OS
- which version of GeoServer
- which type of release (exe on win, cross platform bin, etc... )

Simone.